# Does __autoload() go in the main class?

Tags: php, oop, class-design, methodology

I'm new to classes, so sorry if this is a wicked noob question.

`JMC` is my main class.  Other classes are named like `JMC_files` or `JMC_array`.  I want to use autoload. Does the autoload function go *inside* my main class or *outside* of it? So for a visual, should I do this:

```
class JMC {
    function __autoload($className) {
        include_once($className.'.php');
    }
    protected function foo() { }
}

class JMC_files extends JMC (){
}
```

or this:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    include_once($className.'.php');
}

class JMC {
    protected function foo() { }
}

class JMC_files extends JMC (){
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`__autoload()`](http://wwwphp.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is the name of a magic function that is automatically called by default when you attempt to reference a class that doesn't yet exist in userland. It's a function, not a class method, so you define it like this:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    include_once($className.'.php');
}
```

If you like, you may set your own autoload handler (can be a function or a class method) instead, by using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). For example, if you want to give your main `JMC` class a static `autoload()` method that handles autoloading of class files, you would do something like this:

```
class JMC {
    public static function autoload($className) {
        include_once($className.'.php');
    }

    protected function foo() {}
}

spl_autoload_register('JMC::autoload');

// By referencing this class, if it doesn't yet exist then JMC's autoload()
// gets called and PHP will attempt to load JMC_files.php to look for this class
$files = new JMC_files();
$files->foo();
```

Where you want to place your autoload function depends on you. Your main `JMC` class sounds like a reasonable place for it; my framework's autoload method lives in the main class too.

Comment: So, a) Is there an advantage to defining my own autoload method? and b) If I use the standard `__autoload()` magic function, Would it then make sense to declare that function in my main class definition file?

Comment: a) There's no performance or memory advantage; it's simply for organization purposes. b) If you use your own class's autoload method, there's no need to define `__autoload()`. PHP will look for your class method and run that instead.